# Xinetd: End connection from server script

Tags: netcat, xinetd

I have a xinetd service that is a script and the output is read by netcat on a remote host.

However, when the script on the server exits, netcat still waits although, there won't follow anything. How can I close the connection from the server or maybe send "end of file" or something similar?

**My service:**

```
service myservice
{
   port            = 2222
   socket_type     = stream
   protocol        = tcp
   wait            = no
   server          = /opt/myscript.sh
   user            = root
   disable         = no
}
```

**My script:**

```
#!/bin/sh

##Example:
echo "Hello World!"
```

**Netcat output:**

```
[me@mypc]# nc myhost 2222
Hello World!
*blinking cursor forever*
```

**Output(tail) of `strace nc myhost 2222`:**

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(2222), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
select(4, [3], [3], [3], {tv_sec=10, tv_usec=0}) = 1 (out [3], left {tv_sec=9, tv_usec=999997})
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
select(4, [0 3], [], [], NULL)          = 1 (in [3])
recvfrom(3, "Hello World!\n", 8192, 0, 0x████████████, [128->0]) = 13
write(1, "Hello World!\n", 13Hello World!
)          = 13
select(4, [0 3], [], [], NULL)          = 1 (in [3])
recvfrom(3, "", 8192, 0, 0x████████████, [128->0]) = 0
close(1)                                = 0
select(3, [0], [], [], NULL
```

It just stops there. I then have to ^C so the last line actually looks like:

```
select(3, [0], [], [], NULL^Cstrace: Process 6232 detached
 <detached ...>
```

**Tcpdump:**

```
IP6 localhost.36082 > localhost.myservice: Flags [S], seq 3879998021, win 43690, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3800136568 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP6 localhost.myservice > localhost.36082: Flags [S.], seq 3455514626, ack 3879998022, win 43690, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3800136568 ecr 3800136568,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP6 localhost.36082 > localhost.myservice: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3800136568 ecr 3800136568], length 0
IP6 localhost.myservice > localhost.36082: Flags [P.], seq 1:14, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3800136571 ecr 3800136568], length 13
IP6 localhost.36082 > localhost.myservice: Flags [.], ack 14, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3800136571 ecr 3800136571], length 0
IP6 localhost.myservice > localhost.36082: Flags [F.], seq 14, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3800136571 ecr 3800136571], length 0
IP6 localhost.36082 > localhost.myservice: Flags [.], ack 15, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3800136612 ecr 3800136571], length 0
```

Comment: I could swear I used a similar setup in the past and had not hangup connections.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro after further research I think it has to be udp/dgram if I want to have full control, but I have no idea how and if this can work with a simple script. However it should still terminate  the connection automatically after the script exits... I solved my problem with http(nodejs) and curl wich seems to work nicely, but I'd still like to find out whats the problem with this.

Comment: I implemented exactly the same as your script, and it does not hang. Debian 9 here.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks for testing! I'm on fedora 25. Netcat version: 7.40; Xinetd version: 2.3.15. Maybe its a fedora thing, because apparently, fedora uses a differnt netcat than other linux's.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro then i'll assume its a netcat bug. I'll try to report it somewhere.

Comment: nc 1.10 ; xinetd 2.3.15 here. If it is your nc indeed, I would file a bug as I used tcpdump and xinetd doing it properly and is clearly closing the connection with a FIN

Comment: Are you capable of stracing your netcat and using tcpdump to watch that it is happening?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it's not what I usually do, but I should be able to make it work

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I did a strace, I'm not really familar with it, but it looks like theres a closing bracket missing... (I'm not sure if strace can determine that). However I failed at tcpdump. I tried ´tcpdump´ and ´tcpdump -i lo´, but there was nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60277/discussion-between-rudib-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Comment: sudo tcpdump port 2222

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Ok I added the tcpdump! It was tcpdump port 2222 -i lo (looks like I just didn't see it before)

Comment: Quite odd it being in a select after the close and in the tcpdump nc not answering with a FIN to xinetd FIN. Something is indeed not right there.